# Get location of nuget package directory

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I am creating a nuget package, and I want to make sure that it will work in all scenarios.

In this case, I am adding build targets with the "Build" convention folder.  The target that I am adding needs to know the location of the nuget packages folder.

A lot of the examples I have found assume that they can just use "..\Packages", but Nuget allows you to relocate the packages folder via the nuget.config file.

Is there a way to get the correct location of the nuget packages folder from within a build.targets file?

*(background information)*

I'm writing a package that needs to copy native dlls into the bin directory.  I could use a post build event, but that seems a little hacky.  I would rather include a target that invokes the msbuild <copy> task with SkipUnchangedFiles=true, however for that to work, I need to know the location of the packages folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve the problem described in your background information section you have 2 steps.

A. Ensure the native dlls are copied to the project - edit a section of the nuspec to copy your files into the project root when the package is being built:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    ...
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="install.ps1" target="Tools"/>
    <file src="nativedll1.dll" target="content" />
    <file src="nativedll2.dll" target="content" />
  </files>
</package>
```

B. Create an install.ps1 file (note that I included it in the above sample)
Your install.ps1 file should look something like this.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$file1 = $project.ProjectItems.Item("nativedll1.dll")
$file2 = $project.ProjectItems.Item("nativedll2.dll")

# set 'Copy To Output Directory' to 'Copy if newer'
$copyToOutput1 = $file1.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory")
$copyToOutput1.Value = 2

$copyToOutput2 = $file2.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory")
$copyToOutput2.Value = 2
```

Comment: Do the .dlls get added as references like this?

Comment: No, these are native dlls, so the OP wanted them treated as content. This is the approach you would take if you wanted e.g. to copy some xml files or images to the bin folder.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I read native like 5 times and it wasn't sinking in.

Comment: Accepted as answer.  I would really have liked a way to discover the location of the package directory, because then I would have been able to take advantage of Package Restore, rather than having to add the dlls to the project (and to distributed source control), but this will work.

Answer (score 13):

From within the .targets file, you can access the current file's location using the `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)` property.

Assuming the .targets file is in the nuget build folder, you could get to its own package folder using relative paths like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ThisPackageDirectory>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\</ThisPackageDirectory>
    ...
```

Comment: While the accepted answer solves the underlying problem, this answers the question in the title (getting the location of the NuGet package directory).

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a custom MsBuild task that loads the nuget.config file as an XDocument and get the value of the  element?

Comment: If I need to, I can, but what I'm really looking for with this question is a pre-built way to do this.  I'm just checking to make sure that I need to build something by hand before I sink the work.  Loading the nuget config is easy enough, but nuget configs "cascade" at several levels of the directory structure, so doing it right isn't quite as low-bar as it sounds.  But you are right -- if there is no built-in way to do it, I will have to build my own.

Answer (score 1):

In the install.ps1 file, the $installPath gives you the location of the package directory - all you need to do is go to it's parent like so:

```
$packagesFolder = (get-item $installPath).parent.FullName
```

Comment: That's related to how I ended up really doing it.  I used What you have above helps, but I want that property at build time, rather than at package install.  I ended up doing something very similar to what the SQL server compact edition does -- I used nuget to script a post-build event that copies the dlls from the package location to the bin folder.  That will work as long as everyone has the same location for packages -- because I can only discover the location at package install time, and not at build time.  Thanks, and +1.